# Kubuntu loop after boot

Tags: boot, grub2, kubuntu

I recently installed Kubuntu 18.04.02 LTS in my PC. After first/second use of it, when I power on my PC the kubuntu logo appears and stays there with a black screen.

I'm new in Linux, I installed the NVIDIA GRAPHICS 304.11 driver (if I remember correctly), then this happened, now I'm at the recovery mode waiting for instructions and it stopped there.
I have kubuntu installed on a 400GbSata Hd, a Gtx 550Ti, 8Gb ram  and a Intel core i3

Comment: Please accept the edit and the [edit] it again yourself and add hardware specifications, namely the graphics card.

Comment: Can you do something with this informations now? (Sorry for the errors)

Comment: Yes, thanks. Here's the problem: You installed a legacy driver that doesn't correctly support your card. According to Nvidia it should be 390.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Going to try it right now, sorry for the problems that i had caused ( how i vote up your answer?)

Comment: Not an answer, just a comment. Now I posted an actual answer that you can accept. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The installed driver - 304 - is a legacy driver that doesn't correctly support the GTX550ti.

According to Nvidia it should be 390, a long term support driver branch.

Before installing a new version it's a good practice to purge the previous attempt:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia*
```